# Elasticsearch document count doesn't reflect higher indexing rate

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, document

When we monitor our elasticsearch cluster health through kibana, For a particular index we see very higher indexing rate. But it seems document count doesn't increase proportionally. How to tackle these two.

[image: document count]

[image: indexing rate]

sample document

{
        "_index": "finance_report_fgl_reporting_log",
        "_type": "fgl_reporting_logs",
        "_id": "1907688_POINTS_ACCOUNT_DEBIT",
        "_score": 9.445704,
        "_source": {
          "reportingLogId": {
            "journalId": 1907688,
            "postingAccountId": "POINTS_ACCOUNT",
            "postingAccountingEntry": "DEBIT"
          },
          "journalId": 1907688,
          "journalEventId": "trip_completed",
          "journalEventLogId": "15db1f2b-b9d0-4edd-96f0-c4e4f8e68150",
          "journalAccountingRuleId": "trip_completed_points_payment_rule",
          "journalReferenceId": "174558200",
          "journalGrossAmount": 154.11,
          "postingJournalId": 1907688,
          "postingAccountingRuleId": "trip_completed_points_payment_rule",
          "postingReferenceId": "174558200",
          "postingAccountId": "POINTS_ACCOUNT",
          "postingAccountingPeriod": "2019_08",
          "postingAccountingEntry": "DEBIT",
          "postingCurrencyTypeId": "POINTS",
          "postingAmount": 154.11,
          "accountId": "POINTS_ACCOUNT",
          "accountStakeholderId": "OPERATOR",
          "accountCurrencyTypeId": "POINTS",
          "accountTypeId": "CONTROLLER",
          "accountingRuleId": "trip_completed_points_payment_rule",
          "accountingRuleDescription": "Points payment",
          "eventId": "trip_completed",
          "eventReferenceParam": "body.trip.id",
          "createdDate": "2019-08-29T10:03:32.000+0530",
          "modifiedDate": "2019-08-29T10:03:32.000+0530",
          "createdBy": "ENGINE",
          "modifiedBy": "ENGINE",
          "version": "3.12.6",
          "createYear": 2019,
          "routingKey": "_2019"
        }
      },

Comment: It might be that there are many updates to the same documents. Or that your refresh interval is set very high. Possible?

Comment: Is this indexing rate actual number of documents writing to index

Comment: It's the number of indexing operations running per second

Comment: and my refreshing interval is 10s

Comment: Can you tell a bit more what you are indexing and how (with which client)?

Comment: So if indexing rate is 3000/s after 10s document count should be increased by 30000 right. But its not happening

Comment: I'm repeating my first comment, if the indexing operation is actually an update to an existing document, then the document count wouldn't increase. What are you indexing exactly?

Comment: we are using java client. And my document is a bit bigger one

Comment: Please update your question with your indexing code and a sample document

Comment: No its not updating same document. we are writing different document each time

Comment: Are you're sure the IDs are different for each document? i.e. are you sure that `1907688_POINTS_ACCOUNT_DEBIT` can only identify a single document?

Comment: yes its different for each documet. Is this indexing rate can't be some internal indexing rate

Comment: Let's try a quick experiment. Since your indexing rate is quite high, try running `GET finance_report_fgl_reporting_log/_count` every 10 seconds, do you get different values between each call?

Comment: yes  i have tried it. No i get same count for a long time.

Comment: Then the chart is consistent... there must be something with your IDs, pretty sure your indexing operation are overwriting documents very often because they have the same IDs as existing documents and every few hours you have a new set of documents (with new IDs) and you see the jump in the document count... that's the only explanation I have so far. or it could also be that some of your indexing requests are rejected, but the pattern doesn't look like that...

Comment: Actually ID create combining autoincrement id of table so each document should have different id. Any way thak for your reply

Comment: Can you log what the response of your indexing operations are?

Comment: Yes you are right due to bug in the code it reindexes already indexed documents

Comment: There we go, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this usually happens is because your indexing operations do not create new documents but update existing ones. Mainly because you're sending updates to an ID that already exists.

Every few hours, a new batch of documents is created (according to the jumps in the graphs) because you're creating a new set of IDs.

Make sure to verify how you're creating your IDs as the solution is hidden in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some info when performing `GET _cat/indices?v` check out the "docs.deleted" column, as an update operation is merely a "create new+delete older" operation.